# JS: Unable to bind event dynamically

Tags: jquery

I've `voting mechanism` in my website, if user tries to `vote(up or down)` I'll check whether he logged-in or not, for that I've written following code,

```
      $(".vote").click(function(){
         if(is_logged_in)
          {
             // Doing necessary stuff for vote up/down
          }else
            {
             // Showing Login Dialog box                        
            submitForm(".lform",function(response){

             if(data.status == "1")
               {
                 //Closing the Login Dialog Box
                 is_logged_in = 1;  // Assigning the value
                 bindEvent(".vote","click");  // Binding the Event,but can't able to it
               }
              });//Form Submission Closed
            }// Else Closed
         });// Main 'click' closed

     function bindEvent(selector,eventType){
         $(selector).bind(eventType);
        }
```

Instead of external function `bindEvent(".vote","click")` I've tried without the `bindEvent()`, but I can't able to bind the `click event` dynamically after successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind something to occur on an event you need to pass a callback to be triggered when that event occurs. In your code above you aren't specifying a callback.

```
function bindEvent(selector,eventType){
  $(selector).bind(eventType);
}
```

You need something like this:

```
function bindEvent(selector,eventType,callBack){
  $(selector).bind(eventType, callBack);
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
bindEvent('.target', 'click', function(){
  alert('This will trigger on click!');
})
```

#### update

After re-reading your code it looks to me like what you actually need is to *trigger* the click event, rather than bind something to it:

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
  var $vote = $(this);
  if(is_logged_in) {
    // Doing necessary stuff for vote up/down
  }
  else {
    // Showing Login Dialog box                        
    submitForm(".lform",function(response){
      if(data.status == "1"){
        //Closing the Login Dialog Box
        is_logged_in = 1;  // Assigning the value
        $vote.click();
      }
    });//Form Submission Closed
  }// Else Closed
});
```

Using `click()` is the simple method, or you could use jQuery's `.trigger('click')` method. You may also wish to avoid the click event bubbling up to parent elements, which in this case would make sense, so you could also use `.triggerHandler('click')` instead.

Comment: Actually I don't need callback function here, before posting by question I've tried keeping callback also,but not worked for me.

Comment: @Mahesh.D binding without a second parameter will not do anything. You can either pass a callback or false. Passing false will prevent the event from triggering it's default behaviour, passing a callback will allow you to trigger something on that event. Other than those two options what are you trying to do? because it sounds like you don't need to use `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding dynamically created elements.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".vote",function(){
      if(is_logged_in)
      {
         // Doing necessary stuff for vote up/down
      }
      else
      {
         // Showing Login Dialog box                        
        submitForm(".lform",function(response){

         if(data.status == "1")
           {
             //Closing the Login Dialog Box
             is_logged_in = 1;  // Assigning the value
             bindEvent(".vote","click");  // Binding the Event,but can't able to it
           }
          });//Form Submission Closed
        }// Else Closed
});// Main 'click' closed
```